# Maximizing performance on udp

Tags: c, windows, udp, winsock

im working on a project with two clients ,one for sending, and the other one for receiving udp datagrams, between 2 machines wired directly to each other.
each datagram is 1024byte in size, and it is sent using winsock(blocking).
they are both running on a very fast machines(separate). with 16gb ram and 8 cpu's, with raid 0 drives.
im looking for tips to maximize my throughput , tips should be at winsock level, but if u have some other tips, it would be great also.
currently im getting 250-400mbit transfer speed. im looking for more.
thanks.

Comment: What is the bandwidth of the link between the two machines? Are you sure you don't have a CPU bottleneck (i.e. you're not running in 100% CPU)?

Comment: bandwidth is 1gbps.
no.. cpu is at 30% ~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I don't know what else besides sending and receiving that your applications do it's difficult to know what else might be limiting it, but here's a few things to try.  I'm assuming that you're using IPv4, and I'm not a Windows programmer.

Maximize the packet size that you are sending when you are using a reliable connection.  For 100 mbs Ethernet the maximum packet is 1518, Ethernet uses 18 of that, IPv4 uses 20-64 (usually 20, thought), and UDP uses 8 bytes.  That means that typically you should be able to send 1472 bytes of UDP payload per packet.

If you are using gigabit Ethernet equiptment that supports it your packet size increases to 9000 bytes (jumbo frames), so sending something closer to that size should speed things up.

If you are sending any acknowledgments from your listener to your sender then try to make sure that they are sent rarely and can acknowledge more than just one packet at a time.  Try to keep the listener from having to say much, and try to keep the sender from having to wait on the listener for permission to keep sending.

On the computer that the sender application lives on consider setting up a static ARP entry for the computer that the receiver lives on.  Without this every few seconds there may be a pause while a new ARP request is made to make sure that the ARP cache is up to date.  Some ARP implementations may do this request well before the ARP entry expires, which would decrease the impact, but some do not.

Turn off as many users of the network as possible.  If you are using an Ethernet switch then you should concentrate on the things that will introduce traffic to/from the computers/network devices on which your applications are running reside/use (this includes broadcast messages, like many ARP requests).  If it's a hub then you may want to quiet down the entire network.  Windows tends to send out a constant stream of junk to networks which in many cases isn't useful.

There may be limits set on how much of the network bandwidth that one application or user can have.  Or there may be limits on how much network bandwidth the OS will let it self use.  These can probably be changed in the registry if they exist.

It is not uncommon for network interface chips to not actually support the maximum bandwidth of the network all the time.  There are chips which may miss packets because they are busy handling a previous packet as well as some which just can't send packets as close together as Ethernet specifications would allow.  Additionally the rest of the system might not be able to keep up even if it is.

Answer (score 2):

Some things to look at:

- **Connected UDP sockets** ([some info](http://amailbox.org/node/7491)) shortcut several operations in the kernel, so are faster (see Stevens UnP book for details).
- Socket **send and receive buffers** - play with `SO_SNDBUF` and `SO_RCVBUF` socket options to balance out spikes and packet drop
- See if you can bump up link **MTU** and use **[jumbo frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_frame)**.

Answer (score 1):

use 1Gbps network and upgrade your network hardware...

Answer (score 1):

Test the packet limit of your hardware with an already proven piece of code such as iperf:

http://www.noc.ucf.edu/Tools/Iperf/

I'm linking a Windows build, it might be a good idea to boot off a Linux LiveCD and try a Linux build for comparison of IP stacks.

More likely your NIC isn't performing well, try an Intel Gigabit Server Adapter:

http://www.intel.com/network/connectivity/products/server_adapters.htm

Answer (score 0):

For TCP connections it has been shown that using multiple parallel connections will better utilize the data connection.  I'm not sure if that applies to UDP, but it might help with some of the latency issues of packet processing.

So you might want to try multiple threads of blocking calls.

Comment: im limited to one specific send and receive port.
as i know, you cant have 2 sockets open on the same port..

Answer (score 0):

As well as Nikolai's suggestion of send and recv buffers, if you can, switch to overlapped I/O and have many recvs pending, this also helps to minimise the number of datagrams that are dropped by the stack due to lack of buffer space.

If you're looking for reliable data transfer, consider [UDT](http://udt.sourceforge.net/).